# Directory.Exists not working on server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Dim doesDiretoryExist As Boolean
dim path as string 

path="\\someServer.mycomp.com\ftproot$\folderOne\TestFolder\TESTTWO\"
doesDiretoryExist = Directory.Exists(path)
```

I know this path is correct and has a folder, so doesDiretoryExist  should be true.  When I run my web app locally, it works fine.  But, when I run the app from the IIS server, doesDiretoryExist always returns false.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I need to do to correct it?  Is it due to the fact that the path points to a networked shared folder?

Thanks
jason

Comment: I have you tried doing path = Server.MapPath("\\someServer.mycomp.com\ftproot$\folderOne\TestFolder\TESTTWO\") then passing it into Directory.Exists?  Additionally I would examine what Server.MapPath returns; the directory you think you are passing in might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  It was odd, to check if the directory existed, I needed to use Server.MapPath.  but, if the folder did not exist and I wanted to created it, I had to not use Server.MapPath.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Oh, and you were the first to respond so if you move this to an answer, I'll check it as correct.

Comment: just curious, what does Server.MapPath("\\someServer.mycomp.com\ftproot$\folderOne\TestFolder\TESTTWO\") return? Since the path points to a network folder.

Comment: It returns something like this:  C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyDirectory\PP\MyApp\someServer.myComp.com\ftproot$\folderOne\TestFolder\TESTTWO\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per OP I am moving this from a comment to an answer.

Have you tried doing

```
path = Server.MapPath("\\someServer.mycomp.com\ftproot$\folderOne\TestFolder\TESTTWO\")
```

then passing it into Directory.Exists? Additionally I would examine what Server.MapPath returns; the directory you think you are passing in might not be what you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess it's an identity/permissions issue.  What identity does the application pool that runs this web app use?  It is probably different from what is used when you run locally.  Does that identity have permissions to access that page?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As it turned out, it was as abszero and carl suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You should try and use Server.MapPath plus your path folderone/Testfolder/TESTTWO

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  abszero responded first, so i'll give him the check mark and you the vote up.  If he does not respond in a day, i'll check yours!  Thanks again.